# What is the difference between `ALTER TABLE DISABLE TRIGGER` and `DISABLE TRIGGER`?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, trigger

My company logs DDL on one database using a Database Trigger, looking for DDL including:

- `ALTER_TABLE`
- `CREATE_TRIGGER`
- `ALTER_TRIGGER`
- `DROP_TRIGGER`

When I disable or enable triggers using `ALTER TABLE x DISABLE TRIGGER tiud_x`, this change is logged with the Database Trigger.

When I disable or enable triggers using `DISABLE TRIGGER tiud_x ON x`, this change is not logged.

To me, `DISABLE TRIGGER` and `ENABLE TRIGGER` look like "one weird trick" to avoid firing a database trigger, since they seem to be functionally equivalent. **What's the difference between `ALTER TABLE DISABLE TRIGGER` and `DISABLE TRIGGER`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly:

1. Disabling a trigger is not *altering* the trigger, just like turning off a light is not *altering* the lightbulb. However it is funny that it is not captured by `ALTER_TRIGGER` but something still manages to update `modify_date` when it happens. ¯\-*(ツ)-*/¯
2. Your DDL trigger catches the `ALTER TABLE` variation because that is explicitly *altering the table* - it says so in the command. While you could argue that disabling the trigger is altering the table regardless of the syntax you use (and I would agree with you, especially since the net result is the same), **the difference is** that this is currently a gap in what DDL triggers capture, and there is no `DISABLE_TRIGGER` event (you can vote for them to fix it [in this feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/49db8dc7-5125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0), but that has been sitting there completely ignored for over a decade). [Here is a related, understandably unanswered question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60812333/61305).

   Similarly, a long time ago I remember the `ALTER_` events didn't capture `RENAME`, and this was added as an event later.

You'll have to catch `DISABLE TRIGGER` in other ways, like audit or Extended Events (I talked about this here):

- [When was a table trigger disabled and re-enabled?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27255/1186)

In which case, you may as well capture the `ALTER TABLE` variation the same way so they're both logged in the same place.

A really dumb idea would be to poll `sys.triggers` every n seconds/minutes/hours and log whenever the state of `is_disabled` changes. This won't let you see *who did it* but at least you'll know that it happened and, along with other auditing, you may be able to narrow it down.